# How to have a proper date and time feature in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

| Year | Month | Day | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 8 | 21 | 5 |
| 2022 | 8 | 21 | 6 |

I want the above df as follows

| Date | Time |
| --- | --- |
| 21-08-2022 | 05:00:00 |
| 22-08-2022 | 06:00:00 |

Can anyone please tell me how to do it using python?

Answer (score 1):

Because columns names are exactly `['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']` you can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html),
[`Series.dt.time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.time.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour']])
#if no another columns 
#s = pd.to_datetime(df)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': s.dt.date, 'Time': s.dt.time})
print (df1)
         Date      Time
0  2022-08-21  05:00:00
1  2022-08-21  06:00:00
```